# for of を使ったReverse Stringの挙動が分からない

Tags: javascript

以下のラインでなぜ `abc` という文字列が `cba` と逆になるのか理解できません。

`reversed = char + reversed;`

```js
function reverse(str) {
    let reversed = "";
    for (let char of str) {
        reversed = char + reversed;
    }
    return reversed;
};

console.log(reverse("abc"));
```

Comment: 分からないコードは自分で書きようがないはずで、何か参考にしたページ等があるならそれらも念のため質問文に含めておくと親切かもしれません。/ 恐らくこの辺り？ - [Five Ways to Reverse a String in Javascript](https://medium.com/better-programming/5-ways-to-reverse-a-string-in-javascript-466f62845827)

Comment: forループの中にconsole.logで作業中の文字列を表示する処理を入れて動かせば、どのように逆になっていくか実感出来るでしょう。試してみてください。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「例示は理解の試金石」です。実際にこの関数がどのように動いているのか、各変数の内容を追いながら確かめてみましょう。

まず最初に変数 `reversed` は空文字列 `""` で初期化されます。

```js
let reversed = "";
```

次に問題の for of です。

```js
for (let char of str) {
    reversed = char + reversed;
}
```

最初のループでは、`str` の最初のコードポイントである `"a"` が変数 `char` に代入されます。そして `char + reversed`、つまり `"a" + ""` が新しく `reversed` に代入されます。

```
char = "a", reversed = "a"
```

次のループでは `str` の次のコードポイントである `"b"` が変数 `char` に代入され、`"b" + "a"` が `reversed` に代入されます。

```
char = "b", reversed = "ba"
```

次のループでは `"c"` が `char` に代入され、`"c" + "ba"` が `reversed` に代入されます。

```
char = "c", reversed = "cba"
```

これでループから抜けます。最後に `return reversed` ということで `"cba"` が返されます。

Answer (score 3):

@kunif さんのアドバイスのように下記のスニペットを実行することで、どのように逆になっていくか把握できるのではないでしょうか。

```js
function reverse(str) {
    let reversed = "";
    for (let char of str) {
        console.log("charには'" + char + "'が、reversedには'" + reversed + "'が入っています。");
        console.log("reversedは'" + char + "' + '" + reversed + "'が代入されて'" + char + reversed + "'になります。");
        reversed = char + reversed;
    }
    console.log("forが終わった時点でreversedには'" + reversed + "'が入っています。");
    return reversed;
};

console.log(reverse("abc"));
```

@nekketsuu さんの回答とも類似していますが、せっかく書いたので投稿します。
パソコンに入っているモダンなブラウザならば1行ごとに処理を止めて変数を読み込みながらデバッグ(ステップ実行と言います)もできます。

- [Google Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/?hl=ja)
- [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Tools/Debugger)